# Formatting a value with exactly two decimals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
  
  $('#btn-add').click(function(){
      $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
              $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
          $("input[name='class']").val(parseFloat($(this).val()) + parseFloat($("input[name='class']").val()));
      });
  });
  $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
      $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
          $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
          $(this).remove();
          $("input[name='class']").val(parseInt($("input[name='class']").val() - parseInt($(this).val())));
          total= $("input[name='class']").val(parseInt($("input[name='class']").val() - parseInt($(this).val())));
      });
  
  });
    
   });
    </script>
```

I would like to shorten the number after decimal numbers to 2. Does somebody has any idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toFixed` method.

Your code should be:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
  
      $('#btn-add').click(function(){
          $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
              $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
              $("input[name='class']").val((parseFloat($(this).val()) + parseFloat($("input[name='class']").val())).toFixed(2));
          });
      });

      $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
          $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
              $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
              $(this).remove();
              var newValue = parseInt($("input[name='class']").val() - parseInt($(this).val()));
              $("input[name='class']").val(newValue.toFixed(2));
          });
      });
    
   });
</script>
```

Example output: 2.01

Answer (score 0):

```js
var num = 1.345
console.log(num.toLocaleString('en-UK', { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 }))
console.log(num.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 }))
```

I prefer this format to use different countries. Try it and tell me.